# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' to 'UINavigationController'

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to segue from one view controller to another, and pass data to the next controller.  But I keep getting this error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' to 'UINavigationController'
```

---

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

   if (segue.identifier == "segueLogWaterData") {            
        // pass data to next view
        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let segueViewController = nav.topViewController as! WaterDataViewController 
    }
}
```

This happens with `WaterDataViewController` as a `UITableViewController`.  I've also tried embedding `WaterDataViewController` into a `UINavigationController` but I get a similar error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' to 'MyApp.WaterDataViewController'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A 'UITableViewController' is not a related type to 'UINavigationController'. Since they are not related they can not be case one to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the `segue.destinationViewController` isn't the navigation controller; rather, it is the view controller that the segue is opening. Since `UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, this code should work just fine:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueLogWaterData") {
        let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! WaterDataViewController
        //Assign to dest's properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nav.topViewController is a UITableViewController. Apparently, WaterDataViewController is not a subclass of UITableViewController.

Do you mean to be using rootViewController instead?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error sometimes because of "**omitting class**" to my view controller in the storyboard.