# SIGBRT Error : Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x113ccb7e0) to 'Racing_Weather.PredictorTableViewController' (0x1086645b0)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I am trying to pass data from a UIViewController to UITableViewController and I am getting the above SIGBRT Error `Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x113ccb7e0) to 'Racing_Weather.PredictorTableViewController' (0x1086645b0).`  . I have looked at the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213661/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcontroller-to-uinavigationcontroller). However, this did not seem to work.  I have embedded a UINavigationController and the error appears in the following line `let vc = predictorVC.topViewController as! PredictorTableViewController`
Below is the full function for the segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "getPredictor" {
        let predictorVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let vc = predictorVC.topViewController as! PredictorTableViewController
        vc.predictorTrack = TrackTextField.text!
        vc.firstDriver = firstTextField.text!
        vc.secondDriver = secondTextField.text!
        vc.thirdDriver = thirdTextField.text!


    }
```

Comment: Have you set `PredictorTableViewController` as the class for the destination controller in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your storyboard to make sure that the top view controller in the navigation controller is actually a `PredictorTableViewController`. The error says that it's a `UITableViewController`. You might have to check the Identity Inspector in the top right hand corner of the storyboard editor to see if you have the class set correctly.